# How to Copy Bundle-classpath jars and their dependencies from maven repo to my local lib folder?

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, maven-dependency-plugin

We are developing an **Eclipse RCP** application. We decided to use **SVN** for revision control system. We could export an eclipse product in the eclipse environment. Everything worked fine.

But,

Some of our plugins have dependencies to regular java jars using **bundle-classpath** in their manifest.mf. Up to now we were committing those jars into SVN repository. We "heard" that it is wrong to commit jars into svn and we should use **maven-tycho** and put those jars into a maven repository for this purpose.

So we moved the jars from SVN repository to Maven repository. Then we wanted to setup a fresh dev environment, we checked out projects from svn and they had compilation errors because we do not have jars!

We used **m2eclipse** and define all dependencies in my freshly created **pom.xml** files. **maven-dependency-plugin's copy goal** and list all the jars and then we run mvn validate to get the jars into our lib folder. It worked but it seems to me a bit ugly. Because my plugin's pom.xml looks like defining every dependency twice:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-bundle-classpath-libs</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
                                <artifactId>MyJar</artifactId>
                                <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyJar</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there a way to get rid of this?

Besides if MyJar.pom has other dependencies I need them too in my local lib. Is there a way to **copy those transitive dependencies to my local lib folder**?

I tried **copy-dependencies goal** but it tries to find my other plugins' jars that my plugin depends on. I just need the regular jars to be copied to my local lib. My other plugins are already there side by side with all their source code as a plugin project. I do not need their jars. Can I filter those out? I tried this without success:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeGroupIds>MyGroup</excludeGroupIds>
                <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to decide whether you want transitive dependencies copied or not.

maven-dependency-plugin [1] allows to copy either transitive dependencies ("copy-dependencies" goal, need to add dependencies to dependencies section only in pom) or just certain artifacts without transitive dependencies ("copy" goal, need to add artifacts to plugin's configuration section only).
When using copy-dependencies, you can also include/exclude certain artifactIds from the transitive dependency chain, see [2].

--

[1] http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

[2] http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

Comment: I think the copy-dependencies goal is what I want. I definitely want transitive dependencies. But I do not want plugin dependencies as I have them as a project.

Comment: I tried excludeArtifactIds or excludeGroupIds but still it gives the the same error: Failed to execute goal on project XYZPlugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project MyGroup:XYZPlugin:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: MyGroup:ABCPlugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, in http://myrepo/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of my-public has elapsed or updates are forced.